# Problems with “Test Connectivity” and the Pacletserver

Tags: internet

I know there has been a similar questions to this already but the solution did not work for me so here again:

I have internet connection and I can execute such commands like:

```
Import["http://www.google.com"]
```

I am also able to use the functionality of Wolfram Alpha such as

```
== GDP of the USA
```

but when I do

```
CountryData["France", "Population"]
```

it tells me that there is no connection and that I should test the connectivity which I did via "Edit->Preferences->Internet Connectivity->Test Connectivity". When I tried testing it it returned:

```
"PacletSiteUpdate::err: An error occurred attempting to update paclet information from site http://pacletserver.wolfram.com. Failed writing received data to disk/application"
```

When I tried to ping the `pacletserver.wolfram.com` directly in the cmd it tried to ping `pacletserver2.wolfram.com` which failed. When I did the same with `pacletserver1.wolfram.com` and `pacletserver3.wolfram.com` it worked just fine.

So I tried [Nikita's Solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/problem-with-test-connectivity) with the windows host file which did not work for me.

After that I tried to change the server address within Mathematica with

```
$PacletSite = pacletserver1.wolfram.com
```

After that the Connectivity Test returned success. The CountryData-function did still not work, though. When I re-started Mathematica the `$PacletSite` contains the original value `(http://pacletserver.wolfram.com)` and the Connectivity Test fails again.

Even though the CountryData-function did not work, I think that the problem is that Mathematica tries to connect to `pacletserver2.wolfram.com` and the `$PacletSite`-Value does not influence the CountryData-function.

So is there a way to change the way Mathematica tries to connect to the pacletserver and tell it only to connect to `pacletserver1.wolfram.com` or `pacletserver3.wolfram.com`?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What version of Mathematica is this?

Comment: Mathematica 9.0.1 and I am using Windows 7

Comment: In version 9, try setting ``PacletManager`Services`Private`$wriPacletServerIndex = "1"`` (note that the value is a string). Use "1" or "3", or whatever pacletserverN.wolfram.com value works for you. I might contact you separately to try to determine why the built-in failover mechanism doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: Unfortunatly it did not work. I thin that the built-in failover mechanism works beacuse the problem is just the `http://` value. The original Value of `$PacletSite` is `http://pacletserver.wolfram.com` when I don't change that and set `PacletManager`Services`Private`$wriPacletServerIndex = "1"` the Connectivity Test fails. As soon as I set `$PacletSite = pacletserver.wolfram.com` even without `PacletManager`Services`Private`$wriPacletServerIndex = "1"` the Connectivity Test is successful. The `CountryData`-function still does not work, though. In addition the is default again after a re-start.

Comment: I have the same problem in a user account with non-ASCII characters in the name. Does your Windows user name have accents? Try CountryData["France", "Population"] in your administrator account.

Comment: I changed the account's name but it still does not work

Answer (score 3):

I had EXACTLY the same problem and the cause actually seemed to be a Windows user name with non-ASCII character. 
A simple change of the user name through control panel does not help though as the underlying user name remains the same. 
Creating a new account with only ASCII characters solved the problem for me.

Comment: What's a "underlying user name"? Is there any evidence for its existence? I suspect the issue is not a user name with non-ASCII character, but some kind of unknown residuals. I faced very similar issue (even worse actually, I couldn't even call WolframAlpha or search words that are not function names) recently when updating v8 to v9, and I never used a non-ASCII user name. [Clean start](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3274
) doesn't work, but when I re-install my v9 in a new account, the problem resolved!