# Failure of CountryData due to connectivity?

Tags: warning-messages, curated-data

Today I started researching the "Four colours theorem" and to do so I need data, regions for example. I tried using the following line:

```
CountryData["Ukraine", "Regions"]
```

But the result:

> CountryData::dlfail: Internet download of data for CountryData failed. Use Help > Internet Connectivity... to test or reconfigure internet connectivity. >>

```
$Failed
```

I tried to do this next:

[image: CMD, Ping source]

For those who don't understand (because the screen language is Russian) the default source does not respond.
How I can change the default source? *Mathematica* version – 9.0.1.0, OS – Windows 7.

Comment: It works from my location right now.  Did you try again since then?

Comment: Duplicate? [(29216)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29216/problems-with-test-connectivity-and-the-pacletserver) Some ideas there but no solution, unfortunately.