# WordData [ ] returns ReplaceAll::reps error message

Tags: functions

## Situation:

```
In:= w = WordData[];
During eval of In:= ReplaceAll::reps: {Expression/. Null} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.[>>][1]
During eval of In:= LinkOpen::linke: Specified file is not a MathLink executable..[>>][2]

In:=  WordData["Day", "Definitions"]
Out:=  WordData["Day", "Definitions"]

(*last seems unevaluated...*)

In:=  Here
Out:=  Missing[NotAvailable]
```

### Intention:

I am simply calling this function to use it but its not working.

- I am connected to the internet and I am able to call WolframAlpha["query"] sucessfully...
- Any idea that do not include acrobatics with the Mathematica File System is more than welcome...
- I already check my firewall settings ...

### Here is another one:

```
In:=  CountryData[]
Out:=  DataPaclets`CountryDataDump`$GroupHash["Countries"]
```

- Any ideas...?

### System Info:

```
~$uname -a
Linux ***** 3.16.1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 14 07:40:19 CEST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Network information:

```
In[2]:= SystemInformation["Network"] //Column                                   

Out[2]:= IPAddresses -> {fe80::****:274c:a7c7:***, 192.168.1.145}
        AllowInternetUse -> True
        LoadOnDemand -> True
        LoadOnDemandServers -> {http://pacletserver.wolfram.com}
        LatestTransaction -> Missing[NotActive]
        LatestTransactionServer -> Missing[NotActive]
        LastLocalIndexUpdate -> {2014, 8, 28, 19, 11, 30.766294}
        LastLocalIndexUpdateServer -> {}
        Paclets -> PacletManager Version 2.2.0
        TotalDownloads -> Missing[NotActive]
        DownloadsDirectory -> Missing[NotActive]
```

Mathematica Kernel Information:

```
In[3]:= SystemInformation["Kernel"] //Column                                    

Out[3]:= Version -> 10.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)
        ReleaseID -> 10.0.0.0 (5098646, 5098517)
        LicenseID -> *****-****
        PatchLevel -> 0
        ActivationKey -> ****-9190-****
        ActivationGroupID -> *****-****
        MachineID -> 6539-*****-01360
        UserName -> *****
        MachineName -> ****
        MachineDomains -> {sd.cox.net}
        LicenseServer -> gabriel
        MaxLicenseProcesses -> Infinity
        LicenseExpirationDate -> {Infinity, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        MachineType -> PC
        OperatingSystem -> Unix
        ProcessorType -> x86-64
        Language -> English
        CharacterEncoding -> UTF-8
        SystemCharacterEncoding -> UTF-8
        TimeZone -> -7.
        CreationDate -> DateObject[{2014, 6, 29}, TimeObject[{19, 7, 59}]]
        InstallationDirectory -> /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0
        WSTPVersion -> 4.25 (2014062701)
        ProcessorCount -> 2
        LicenseSubprocesses -> 1
        MaxLicenseSubprocesses -> Infinity
```

I also tried `Trace` and `TracePrint` on the `WordData[]` function call. *Nothing clear so far ...*

This is a ***[*link*](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arthur-schopenhauer/Mathematica_Notebooks/master/CountryDataTracePrint.nb) to the output*** of:

```
System`Dump`AutoLoad[Hold[CountryData], Hold[CountryData], "DataPaclets`CountryData`"] // TracePrint
```

Wolfram Documentation:

[ReplaceAll::reps error docs.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Replace/reps.en.html)

  
[LinkOpen::linke error docs.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/LinkOpen/linke.html)

Comment: Please include the details of your system, e.g. *Mathematica* version, platform, etc.

Comment: Possibly related: [(29216)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29216), [(39110)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39110).  No solutions there, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard I will take a closer look to this issue later on... I will post here the response from wolfram support... thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution (This solution worked for my particular case.)

### *Install Mathematica 9 alongside with Mathematica 10 then reinstall Mathematica 10*

- I have no idea why it worked.  I do not have enough time now to find out. I will appreciate any comments for a further research of an answer...
- If you use *Arch Linux* install tree with:

  ```
  $ sudo pacman -S tree
  ```

  The purpose of this is to see clearly the structure of your installation directory.
- This the output of the *tree* program after *cd* into the *$InstallationDirectory*

  `` $ tree -af </code></pre>
  Oops... the output of the `tree` program on the `$InstallationDirectoryis about <em>60,000 lines...</em> In simple terms I installed both versions of Mathematica and the issue with theIn1:= WordData[ ]` call was gone. ``
- *Mathematica* 10 lives now on `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/` and *Mathematica* 9 on /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/ ...
- Here is a screenshot of a happy ending... [image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Trace.html) the `WordData` problem because I don't have that error on my system.  Howvever after loading `CountryData[]` you should have this behavior:

```
DataPaclets`CountryDataDump`$GroupHash["Countries"] // Short
```

> ```
> {Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, AmericanSamoa, << 233 >>, Yemen, Zambia, Zimbabwe}
> ```

That you do not indicates that this definition was never properly loaded.

The definition of `CountryData` on my system, before using `CountryData[]`:

```
CountryData := 
 System`Dump`AutoLoad[Hold[CountryData], Hold[CountryData], "DataPaclets`CountryData`"] /;
   System`Dump`TestLoad
```

You should first check to see that `` System`Dump`TestLoad `` returns `True`:

```
System`Dump`TestLoad
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Next, please check and report the output of this:

```
mx = System`Private`$SystemFileDir <> System`Dump`fixfile["DataPaclets`CountryData`"] <> "x"

FileByteCount[mx]
```

On my machine:

> ```
> "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
> Research\\Mathematica\\10.0\\SystemFiles\\Kernel\\SystemResources\\Windows-x86-64\\\
> DataPaclets\\CountryData.mx"
>
> 10532
> ```

Comment: @Schopenhauer Okay, next check added to my "answer."

Comment: I guess there is no other way but to dive into the file system ... _no luck still_ ```Out:= /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Kernel/SystemResources/Linux-x86-64/DataPaclets/CountryData.mx``` ```In:=FileByteCount[mx]``` ```Out:= 10626``` ```<< "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Kernel/\
SystemResources/Linux-x86-64/DataPaclets/CountryData.mx"``` ```In:= CountryData[]``` ```Out:= DataPaclets`CountryDataDump`$GroupHash["Countries"]```

Comment: @Schopenhauer Please include the full output of ``System`Dump`AutoLoad[Hold[CountryData], Hold[CountryData], "DataPaclets`CountryData`"] // TracePrint`` in your Question.  (Run the command in a fresh kernel.)

Comment: [_Here_](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/arthur-schopenhauer/Mathematica_Notebooks/master/CountryDataTracePrint.nb) is the output of: ```System`Dump`AutoLoad[Hold[CountryData], Hold[CountryData], "DataPaclets`CountryData`"] // TracePrint```